# How to use Counter with a list of dicts in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

Having a list like this, I can get groups of the same values by:

```
N = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
C = Counter(N)
print([[k, ] * v for k, v in C.items()])
```

getting the following result.

```
[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5,5]]
```

However if I have the following list

```
N = [{'doc':'A','value':300,'W':1},{'doc':'B','value':301,'W':0.5},{'doc':'C','value':301,'W':0.45},{'doc':'D','value':301,'W':0.3},{'doc':'E','value':300,'W':1},]
```

I want to group in the same way that the previous one, using the key 'value' to group them, namely:

```
[[{'doc':A,'value':300,'W':1}, {'doc':'E','value':300,'W':1}],[{'doc':'B','value':301,'W':0.5},{'doc':'C','value':301,'W':0.45},{'doc':'D','value':301,'W':0.3}]]
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for this problem.

`collections.Counter` is only useful for incrementing integer counters, and even then [only with hashable objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). This isn't what you are looking to do here.

```
from collections import defaultdict

N = [{'doc':'A','value':300,'W':1}, {'doc':'B','value':301,'W':0.5},
     {'doc':'C','value':301,'W':0.45}, {'doc':'D','value':301,'W':0.3},
     {'doc':'E','value':300,'W':1},]

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in N:
    d[i['value']].append(i)

res = list(d.values())

# [[{'W': 1, 'doc': 'A', 'value': 300}, {'W': 1, 'doc': 'E', 'value': 300}],
#  [{'W': 0.5, 'doc': 'B', 'value': 301},
#   {'W': 0.45, 'doc': 'C', 'value': 301},
#   {'W': 0.3, 'doc': 'D', 'value': 301}]]
```

---

As an aside, this also presents a more direct solution to your first problem:

```
N = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in N:
    d[i].append(i)

res = list(d.values())

# [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done with a Counter, for multiple reasons:

1. Integers are hashable, dicts are not. `Counter` only works with hashable values.
2. All the grouped integers are the same, but the dicts are not. Only the "value" key of the dicts you're grouping is the same. Even if `Counter` worked with dicts, it would only keep 1 dict per group and discard the rest.

---

The solution here is to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of a `Counter`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

N = [{'doc':'A','value':300,'W':1},{'doc':'B','value':301,'W':0.5},
     {'doc':'C','value':301,'W':0.45},{'doc':'D','value':301,'W':0.3},
     {'doc':'E','value':300,'W':1}]

groups = defaultdict(list)
for dic in N:
    groups[dic['value']].append(dic)

result = list(groups.values())
# [[{'W': 1, 'doc': 'A', 'value': 300}, {'W': 1, 'doc': 'E', 'value': 300}],
#  [{'W': 0.5, 'doc': 'B', 'value': 301},
#   {'W': 0.45, 'doc': 'C', 'value': 301},
#   {'W': 0.3, 'doc': 'D', 'value': 301}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about simple manual approach without any import :

```
N = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

d={}

for i,j in enumerate(N):
    if j not in d:
        d[j]=[j]
    else:
        d[j].append(j)

print(d)
```

output:

```
{1: [1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3, 3], 4: [4, 4, 4, 4], 5: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]}
```

or:

```
print(d.values())
```

output:

```
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```